# Inequality for complete norms

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $\| \cdot \|_1$ and $\| \cdot \|_2$ be complete norms on a vector space $X$ (which is not finite dimensional).

I would like to show that the inequality $\| x \|_1 \le C \| x \|_2$ implies the inequality $\| x \|_2 \le D \| x \|_1$ for some $C, D$.

First of all I would like to ask what is the definition of complete norms (I tried to solve that problem thinking of them as norms with limits in $X$). I haven't found any help in my sources. Secondly I would like to ask for some help in finding the solution to the problem above.

Comment: is $X$ finite dimensional?

Comment: @JustDroppedIn No.

Comment: "Complete norms" means that $(X, \lVert\cdot\rVert_1)$ and $(X, \lVert\cdot\rVert_2)$ are both Banach spaces. Try using the open mapping theorem, applying it to the identity operator.

Comment: @JustDroppedIn: there are subtleties. The question asks to show that, if one norm dominates the other, then they are equivalent. It does NOT ask to show that any two norms are equivalent.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Yes, I spoke too fast, I deleted the comment

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro can you provide some more tips, please? I tried using this theorem with no success however.

Comment: The identity operator $(X,\|\cdot\|_2)\to(X,\|\cdot\|_1)$ operator is bounded. By open mapping theorem, it is invertible, i.e. the identity operator $(X,\|\cdot\|_1)\to(X,\|\cdot\|_2)$ is bounded, which is what you want to prove

Comment: @JustDroppedIn, thank you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complete norms are norms in relation to which the space is Banach. Let $X_1$ be $X$ with norm $\|\cdot\|_1$, $X_2$ be $X$ with norm $\|\cdot\|$, then $X_1$ and $X_2$ is banach spaces. By condition $\|x\|_1\leq C\|x\|_2$. Consider the operator $A:X_2\to X_1$ such that $Ax=x$. It's clear that $D(A)=X_2$, $R(A)=X_1$, $A$ -- linear, bounded and bijective. Then exists inverse operator $A^{-1}:X_1\to X_2$, moreover, $A^{-1}x=x$ and by Banach's inverse operator theorem $A^{-1}$ is bounded. Thus $\|A^{-1}x\|_2\leq\|A^{-1}\|\|x\|_1$, therefore $\|x\|_1\geq\|A^{-1}x\|_2\|A^{-1}\|^{-1}$. Finally, $\|A^{-1}x\|_2=\|x\|_2$.

Comment: That's a very clear explanation. Thank you!